# NSViewController or NSWindowController to manage nib

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nib, nswindowcontroller, nsviewcontroller

As far as good practices and resource usages (memory, etc.), Which is preferable method to use NSViewController or NSWindowController if either method satisfied what I try to do.  Opening another nib from another nib.  I can accomplish using either one.  The only differences are the instantiating syntax and calling syntax as below (initWithNibName vs. initWithWindowNibName and [nib view] vs [nib showWindow:sender])

Any comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the names imply, they serve different purposes. If you want to load a window, use `NSWindowController`, if you load a view, use `NSViewController`.